# Mongo Distinct Index for Dot Notated

Tags: mongodb, indexing, distinct

1. I have a mongodb v4.2.2 hosted on Atlas. Have a collection
   `objects` and two fields in it: `metadata` as array of objects, each
   object has one field `key` AND second field named as `model`. Added compound index
   `model->metadata.key` as regular one. While running db command
   `db.objects.explain('executionStats').distinct('metadata.key',
   {model: ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')})` from console it
   doesn't use my `model->metadata.key` index and doesn't use DISTINCT_SCAN.
2. But if I move data to another collection lets say `objectKeys` that
   has two fields like `key`, `model` and again add regular compound
   index `model->key` and run command
   `db.objectKeys.explain('executionStats').distinct('key', {model:
   ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')})` it is successfully applying DISTINCT_SCAN
   and use the index.
3. Question. How to force MongoDB to use indexes for dot notated
   field during distinct operation?

**UPDATE DETAILS:**

1.

```
db.objects.getIndexes();
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
    "model" : 1,
    "metadata.key" : 1,
    "metadata.value" : 1
  },
  "name" : "model_1_metadata.key_1_metadata.value_1",
  "ns" : "my_db.objects",
  "background" : true
}

db.objects.explain('executionStats').distinct('metadata.key', {model: ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')})

"executionStages" : {
  "stage" : "FETCH",
    "nReturned" : 0,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 1,
    "advanced" : 0,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "docsExamined" : 0,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
      "nReturned" : 0,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      "works" : 1,
      "advanced" : 0,
      "needTime" : 0,
      "needYield" : 0,
      "saveState" : 0,
      "restoreState" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "keyPattern" : {
      "model" : 1,
        "metadata.key" : 1,
        "metadata.value" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "model_1_metadata.key_1_metadata.value_1",
      "isMultiKey" : true,
      "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "model" : [ ],
        "metadata.key" : [
        "metadata"
      ],
        "metadata.value" : [
        "metadata"
      ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
      "isSparse" : false,
      "isPartial" : false,
      "indexVersion" : 2,
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
      "model" : [
        "[ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d'), ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')]"
      ],
        "metadata.key" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ],
        "metadata.value" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
      "seeks" : 1,
      "dupsTested" : 0,
      "dupsDropped" : 0
  }
}
```

2.

```
db.object_keys.getIndexes();

{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
    "models" : 1,
    "key" : 1
  },
  "name" : "models_1_key_1",
  "ns" : "my_db.object_keys",
  "background" : true
},

db.object_keys.explain('executionStats').distinct('key', {models: ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')})

"executionStages" : {
  "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
    "nReturned" : 0,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
    "works" : 1,
    "advanced" : 0,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 0,
    "restoreState" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "transformBy" : {
    "_id" : 0,
      "key" : 1
  },
  "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "DISTINCT_SCAN",
      "nReturned" : 0,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      "works" : 1,
      "advanced" : 0,
      "needTime" : 0,
      "needYield" : 0,
      "saveState" : 0,
      "restoreState" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "keyPattern" : {
      "models" : 1,
        "key" : 1
    },
    "indexName" : "models_1_key_1",
      "isMultiKey" : true,
      "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "models" : [
        "models"
      ],
        "key" : [ ]
    },
    "isUnique" : false,
      "isSparse" : false,
      "isPartial" : false,
      "indexVersion" : 2,
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
      "models" : [
        "[ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d'), ObjectId('5e18aff58a5aaffdc3d6f26d')]"
      ],
        "key" : [
        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
      ]
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0
  }
}
```

So as you can see in the first case it uses IXSCAN means index scan and in the second case it uses DISTINCT_SCAN that is considered more faster. The differences is that in first case the `metadata` field is array of objects and in the second case the field `key` is string

Comment: Can you provide an example of indexed document, the way you're creating the index and the query you're analyzing? Anyway, `DISTINCT_SCAN` is not totally compatible with multi-key indexes.

Comment: Please post a _sample document_ from the collection. Also, post the output from the `db.collection.getIndexes()` on that collection.

Comment: @prasad_ replied

Comment: The info you have posted in not clear. Please post the **document structure** (a sample document you are working with) for  and **all indexes**  for _each_ of them.

Comment: @prasad_ there is no other indexes for the fields. You do not need document structure in particular problem. The problem is in index not in field. Everything I could and you needed is posted. Please specify the question that is not clear for you.